# VS Code me esta borrando constantemente el fichero server.php de mi proyecto de Laravel y no me deja crearlo de nuevo manualmente

Tags: laravel, git, vscode

No se que porque razon **vscode** me esta borrando el fichero `server.php`. Y cuando lo intento crear manualmente me dice que **no tengo permisos** (estoy en windows). Este fichero contiene lo siguiente:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

Por lo que entiendo, este fichero se supone es el que bindea el servidor que creas con `php artisan serve`. Por tanto no me deja acceder.

---

```
$ git status
On branch feature/improving_tests
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    server.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Al intentar restaurarlo:

```
$ git checkout -- server.php
error: unable to create file server.php: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya he encontrado el problema, no era VSCODE, era el antivirus, que estaba almacenando en el contenedor de virus el servicio `svchost.exe` y no me dejaba funcionar el servidor, le he dicho que cree una excepcion y listo. Todo funciona bien de nuevo.